# How do I get my Microsoft Word 2013 pages to align on top of each other?

Tags: microsoft-word, formatting, microsoft-word-2013

As in, I don't want the pages on my screen to show like a quadrant, where page one is on the top left, then for page two it goes to the right, then page three goes below page one, and page four goes below page 2. I want them all to stack on top of each other, and just scroll down.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this works for 2013 because I am using 2010.

1. Go to the View tab on the Office Ribbon.
2. Click Print Layout and in Document Views.
3. Click 100% in Zoom.

Comment: @JaredFisher You're welcome! :D